# Extbase Query filter by child in ObjectStorage

Tags: typo3, extbase

So I have a `Item` model which has a `Recipe` 1:1 relation.

The Recipe (model) has an ObjectStorage containing 1:n CraftingMaterials (model) which are needed for crafting. Each CraftingMaterial has an `amount` field and one relation to an Item (model)

Model Dump:

[image]

```php
public function findItemUsedIn($item)
{
    $query = $this->createQuery();
    $query->matching(
        $query->logicalAnd(
            $query->in('material.item', [$item])
        )
    );
    return $query->execute();
}
```

`material.item` should be an ObjectStorage/Collection of Items.

So my goal is to filter if they contain the `$item` to find all recipes which got this item assigned, but Extbase cannot find any results. The backend runs fine and I can assign all these items.

Somehow Extbase hang up materials being an object storage and tries to match the id of the material relation and not the item one level deeper.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confusing `in()`and `contains()`. As in() checks if a single-valued property exists in a multi-value operand, the latter method contains() checks if a multi-valued property contains a single-valued operand.

```
public function findItemUsedIn($item)
{
    $query = $this->createQuery();
    $query->matching(
        $query->logicalAnd(
            $query->contains('material', $item)
        )
    );
    return $query->execute();
}
```